# Highcharts rangeSelector for multiple charts

Tags: highcharts

I have 4 charts which contain multiple series. Is it possible to have the rangeSelector() change all charts at once?

Even more desirable would be using the sliding master detail which is enabled like so: $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', { ....

If it's possible could someone point me to references or examples

thanks in advance,

MAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use afterSetExtremes() to catch event form one chart, and use setExtrmes to set range on the others charts. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes()

Comment: That looks like what I need. Unfortunately my JavaScript skills suck. I'm guessing a listener on the remaining charts to set new extremes? I haven't a clue where to start. btw thanks for the accurate help and quick reply

Comment: Just found this, could be a start.                                // Specific event listener
    Highcharts.addEvent(chart.xAxis[0], 'afterSetExtremes', function (e) {
        console.log('Set extremes to ' + e.min + ', ' + e.max);
    });

Comment: Sebastian, I'm still struggling with this, any chance you could look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/help/eof6du4f/

Comment: Could you let me know what is incorrect with that example?

Comment: sorry about that, guess i forgot to save jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/help/eof6du4f/1. I'd like to be able to control both or more charts with one rangeSelector. It doesn't have to be live. Maybe when the selector stops? I've tried numerous variations but I just don't seem to have a grip on getExtremes, afterSetExtremes, or setExtremes. I couldn't find an example online. Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: Also, this is the sight I'm trying to use it on, http://capecodbay.webfactional.com/, it has 5 graphs

Comment: Sebastion, here's th correct jsfiddle,  jsfiddle.net/help/eof6du4f/1

Comment: A few clues: min/max needs to me timestamp, not formatted dates. Second is incorrect reference to 2 chart. During initialisation there jquery return nothing. So you need to refer to this after initialisation. Check demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eof6du4f/3/